# Nested groups in ejabberd

Tags: ejabberd, rosters

I am trying to create nested groups in ejabberd's mod_shared_roster corresponding to the organizational structure of my enterprise, similar to this:

```
Group1
 - Subgroup1-1
 - Subgroup1-2
Group2
 - Subgroup2-1
   - Subgroup2-1-1
   - Subgroup2-1-2
 - Subgroup2-2
...
```

Using web interface I can only make one-level flat group structure.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This depends in the client. For example, Tkabber supports nested groups (Preferences -> Roster -> Nested and Nested_delimiter), and I have configured :: as delimiter.

Then, in the ejabberd webadmin, I create groups:

```
g1
Name: Group1

sg11
Name: Group1::Subgroup1-1
Members: user1@localhost usergroup1-1@localhost
Displayed Groups: sg11
```

When user1 logins, he gets the usergroup1-1 contact and is displayed in a nested group Group1->Subgroup1-1